# How to ignore constraints without any validator registered using Hibernate validator (JSR303)?

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am using Hibernate validator to validate Java classes. For some custom constraints, they are no validator defined (they are supposed to be dynamically provided in some other context).

```java
  /** Name: NBR00001 Description: Some business rule **/
  @Documented
  @Constraint(validatedBy = {})
  @Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  @interface NBR00001 {
    String message() default
        "NBR00001: Business rule description";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
  }
```

I don't want to define a dummy validator constraint for each of those which I know I could do with Java service loader.

Is there a way to configure Hibernate validator to ignore constraint without any validator registered?

Here is the error which I would like to ignore:

> "message":"HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint